# How to split the list into chunks with equal size and if the list is odd I want to add the chunk the previous chunk

Tags: python, list, function

If the dataset contains n=385, now I want to split so each chunk contains the points like 95,95,95,95,5. Now I want to add the last 5 points to previous chunk

I am running on jupyter notebook

```
def chunks(l, n):
   return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

slice =chunks(dataframe, int(len(dataframe)/4))
```

I expected the output into equal sized

Comment: for `chunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3)`, will your output be `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`, where I append the last element to the second last sublist?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119142/10366273

Answer (score 0):

```python
def chunks (l, n):
  r = [l]
  while len (r [-1]) >= 2 * n:
    r [-1:] = [r [-1][:n], r [-1][n:]]
  return r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition where if the last chunk is not of your desired length, the function adds it to the previous chunk and returns only until that index. For example:

```
def chunks(l, n):
  foo = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
  if len(foo[-1]) != n:
    foo[-2]+= foo[-1]
    return foo[:-1]
  else:
    return foo


l = [i for i in range(100)]

chunks = chunks(l, 6)
print(chunks)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
...
 [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89], 
 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the second last sublist of the list in your existing code by adding the last sublist, and then removing the last sublist, only if the last sublist is not of size n, the chunk size

```
def chunks(l, n):
   li = [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
   #Add the second last sublist to the last sublist
   #Only if the last sublist is not of size n
   if len(li[-1]) != n:
        li[-2] += li[-1]
        #Remove the last element
        li.pop(-1)
   return li
```

The output will be

```
print(chunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],3))
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(chunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3))
#[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: This fails the purpose if `n` is a multiple of `len(l)`