# Divide a Python list every n-element

Tags: python, list

Recently, I've found a code for developing a set of lists from a list, that code was written by user [Mai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2593536/mai), answering [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119070/how-to-divide-a-list-into-n-equal-parts-python) but i have not understood it yet. Could somebody help me to understand it? And... is there a way to rewrite that code that be easier? The code is:

```
def even_divide(lst, num_piece=4):
    return [
        [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if (i % num_piece) == r]
        for r in range(num_piece)
    ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide code to replicate the problem and be more specific in your question. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @mm_ I was not understanding how the variable r is working and what was the internal working of the operator % in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually. Just follow through the values of the two loops:

Starting with the outer loop, `r` would be `0`, then `1`, then `2`, etc. Let's look at the case for which `r == 1`. When running through the different values of `i`, (which would be `0, 1, 2, ... len(lst)`, the value of `i % 4`, meaning the remainder of dividing `i` by `4`, would be `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. So the `i % 4` would be *equal* to `r`, for every 4 values of `i`!

For our chosen `r == 1`, that would mean we're *choosing* `lst[1], lst[5], lst[9], ...`, etc.

And for `r == 2`? You guessed it! You'd be picking up `lst[2], lst[6], lst[10],...`.

So over all you'd get 4 lists, with non-overlapping elements of the original list, by just "jumping" 4 elements every time, but starting at different values.

Which naturally leads to the more simple solution:

```
def even_divide(lst, num_piece=4):
    return [lst[r::num_piece] for r in range(num_piece)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Also more "pythonic" I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Could somebody help me to understand it?

Sure! It's a list comprehension. A list comprehension takes a list and does something to or with every element in that list. Let's say I want to multiply every element in my list by 2:

`new_list = [element*2 for element in my_list]`

What makes it a list comprehension is the bracket syntax. For those new to it, that's usually the part that takes a moment to get used to. With that said, I assume that is what is giving you difficulty in understanding the code in your question, as you have a list comprehension in a list comprehension. It might be difficult to understand now, but list comprehensions are a wonderful thing in python.

But, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3013449/11323304) mentions, there's a lot of discussions around list comprehension, lambda's, map, reduce, and filter. Ultimately, its up to you to decide what's best for your project. I'm not a fan of anything else but list comprehensions, so I use those religiously.

Based on the question you've linked, the list comprehension takes a 1d list of length x and turns it into a 2d list of (length x, width y). It's like [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

> And... is there a way to rewrite that code [to] be easier?

I would not recommend it. List comprehensions are considered very pythonic and you will see them everywhere. Best to use them and get used to them.

Comment: I had not asked before here and I didn't expected such good answers. Thank you so much for you time, I´ll continue studying it.