# Divide a list into smaller lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that could divide a list into smaller lists, as follows, I have a list and a value like that:

```
nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
N = 3
```

I want to get smaller `N` lists depends on the length of `nb_classes` and the value of `N`.

If the value of `N` is 3 for example, I want to have 3 small lists like that :

```
nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [4,5,6]
list_3 = [7,8,9]
```

Second example :

```
nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [5,6,7]
list_3 = [8,9,10]
```

Third example :

```
nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
list_3 = [9,10,11]
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what if the length is 11? You will get 4-4-3?

Comment: Yes, thank you I forgot to mention that

Comment: Would you say you want the overflow from the remainder to spill into the first elements of the lists?

Comment: Surely, for this task divisibility by 3 is more important than divisibility by 2 (i.e., odd/evenness)?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119142/10043695) answers your question. (The `slice_list()` function)

Comment: yes @Schnitte you are right, so how do I do the division according to the value of N

Comment: If N is 3, and the length of the list is evenly divisible by three, then `list_1 = nb_classes[:(len(nb_classes) / 3)]`, `list_2 = nb_classes[(len(nb_classes) / 3):2*(len(nb_classes) / 3)]`, `list_3 = nb_classes[2*(len(nb_classes) / 3):]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I hardly tried to make it in one line. Here is what I ended up with

```
import math

nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
N = 3

lists = [nb_classes[math.ceil(i): math.ceil(i + len(nb_classes) / N)] for i in (len(nb_classes) / N * j for j in range(N))]

print(lists)  # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

But this may be a little bit complicated, you just need to ceil your indexes

Comment: @KellyBundy, You are right. I'll try to fix it now

Comment: Yes @KellyBundy, I was just about to say this

Comment: I updated it, please check)

Comment: @KellyBundy, I accidentally wrote some (in the end) easy stuff wrong)

Comment: Now gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @KellyBundy there is a missing `]` in the end.

Comment: @3nws, yea copying from ubuntu terminal is not so easy)

Answer (score 5):

There's a straightforward way using `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`

```py
import itertools

def split_list(lst, n=3):
    lengths = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    # set the lengths of each sublist correctly
    for _, idx in zip(range(len(lst)), itertools.cycle(range(n))):
        lengths[idx] += 1

    iterator = iter(lst)

    for length in lengths:
        yield itertools.islice(iterator, length)
```

Note that this returns a generator expression which produces `islice` objects, which are themselves iterators not lists. If you *actually* need lists here, you'll have to make them yourself.

```py
import itertools  # as before

def split_list(lst):
    # as before, until...

    iterator = iter(lst)

    # instead of the for loop leading to the yield, instead use...
    return [list(itertools.islice(iterator, length)) for length in lengths]
```

Comment: Doesn't produce any lists.

Comment: Could you replace `range(3)` for `range(N)`? and `lengths` to `[0]*N`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan you could of course, but the question indicated you should always divide into 3. An aside: `[0]*N` can, on occasion, be dangerous -- prefer `[0 for _ in range(N)]`. This won't matter for `[0]` but if your "filler" object is mutable you end up with `N` references to the _same_ object in the multiplication case but not the list comprehension. Try `lst = [[]] * 3; lst[0].append(1); assert lst[1][0] == 1`

Comment: @KellyBundy true but you know as well as I do that users rarely _actually_ need lists. If they do then collate in the function and return the whole. I'll add that in my answer.

Comment: *Maybe* it's not what they need, but that's what the question asks for. And I strongly disagree that people rarely need lists.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's a fair criticism. I adjusted the answer to add an alternate form that returns the real memory-consuming lists instead :). It's certainly arguable whether folks really need a list, but typically if you're using a list (and not an object or a tuple) then you have a bunch of something and rarely -- at least in my experience -- do you need more than one of them at a time. The only advantage that lists have over iterators in that situation is that you can't exhaust a list! :)

Comment: Yes, being able to iterate multiple times is kind of a significant feature. Anyway, if you're using itertools anyway, I'd do `lengths = chain(repeat(q + 1, r), repeat(q, 3 - r))` with `q` and `r` as in Pychopath's answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy ah yeah that'd be more performant for sure! It's a little less obvious what's happening though, at least to me. I don't want to think about the math that hard -- treat it like dealing cards and "add one" in a cycle until we're done and that's perfect for me.

Comment: Could even [remove your second loop](https://tio.run/##TU/NasMwDL77KXS0aQbrehmDvUJfobiJ0ggc2ZXVQZ8@k5PsRyeh71flqVPm03uRZRklz0CKojmnCjSXLAr9FIk7ECwYtQOqiXp0bsARakmkl0RVfaqGncOHA5u70eETBvqa8@ATcoNDw1fYDjedqjFWb79Z@zsc4GjK8BPmzecML3bZdIL6EIY5Fr@1@CW20muGaXf34NyYBRiIQSLf0L@97vX4eulTrBVbhbX9RrBwPhz3sCLE9lZDW2Bbuv8P/5l0cAo2y/IN) as well. Btw, actually the question asks for N sublists, with N=3 only being an example. And it already did when you posted your answer, their edit beating you by two seconds :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy haha now we're getting into code golf territory. This is where I expect the author to walk me through their logic in the code review :). I did edit to allow for `n` sublists, given the two second skew ;)

Comment: Nah, not code golf. Speed. Trying to move everyting into C code. The `[0 for _ in range(n)]` btw really makes it look like you don't understand mutable and immutable. I know you do, I'm just telling you that's what it looks like.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll run that risk ;)

Answer (score 1):

Divide to get quotient and remainder. Normal sublist length is `q`, but the first `r` sublists get an extra element:

```
def divide(lst, N):
    q, r = divmod(len(lst), N)
    i = 0
    return [lst[i : (i := i + q + (j < r))]
            for j in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```py
def splitlist(mylist: list,n: int):
    lst = mylist
    res_list = []
    while lst:
        if len(lst) < n:
            # Not sure if the ValueError is approptiate
            raise ValueError()
        if len(lst) % n == 0:
            slice_at_idx = n

        else:
            # next slice will be n+1 size (4 in your case)
            slice_at_idx = n+1
        res_list.append(lst[:(slice_at_idx)])
        lst = lst[(slice_at_idx):]
    
    return res_list
            


nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
N = 3

print(splitlist(nb_classes,N))

nb_classes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

# if you know the resulting amount of lists
lst_1,lst_2,lst_3 = splitlist(nb_classes,N)
```