# get such a number of elements as a percentage from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a function that will allow me to extract a subset from a defined list. Note that the function returns two things:

- The original list with the subset removed S = S - S'
- the new list which contains only the subset S'

Example :

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_list = get_purcentage(list, purcentage = 0.3)

# list should now be : 
# list =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# new_list should now be : 
# new_list =  [8, 9, 10]
```

I tried to use a library like `train_test_split` from  `sklearn.model_selection` and it works as I want it to, but I would like to have my own code

**Note:** the order doesn't matter, the items can be taken randomly

Comment: So, let's say a list has 12 elements and the percentage is 0.5, we just need to return the 1st 6 elements as one list and 2nd 6 as the second list?

Comment: Please note that `list` is the name of a rather import class right up until the point that you reset it to be a specific instance of that class.

Comment: Just curious: Is this related to your similar previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71734923/12671057)? (If yes, how so?)

Comment: What if the percentage isn't an integer, e.g., if you want 30% of a list with 7 elements (so you want 2.1 elements)?

Comment: If you are curious, I wrote a function that allows me to divide a data set over N clients (an unballanced distribution) , each client  has a majority of certain classes and has a small slice of the other classes, like the following example : client_1 has [ 90% of the total data of class 0, 90% of class 1, 90% of class 2, 5% of class 3, ...].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from random import shuffle

def get_percentage(lst, percentage):
    shuffle(lst)
    result = []
    for _ in range(int(len(lst) * percentage)):
        result.append(lst.pop())
    return result
```

Now you can use the new function in this way:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_lst = get_percentage(lst, percentage=0.3)
```

**Important:**

The `get_percentage` function modifies the input `lst` list!! The advantage is that it's not creating a new list from scratch.

**EDIT**
If you don't care about randomness then things are even easier:

```
def get_percentage(lst, percentage):
    result = []
    for _ in range(int(len(lst) * percentage)):
        result.append(lst.pop())
    return result
```

If it's fine to create new lists and use the function in a different way:

```
def get_percentage(lst, percentage):
    n = int(len(lst) * percentage)
    return lst[n:], lst[:n]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
lst, new_lst = get_percentage(lst, percentage=0.3)
```

Comment: Now I'm just looking forward to their next question about why 70% of a list with 90 elements only gives them 62 elements instead of 63 :-)